# rake db:seed error for Rails app using MongoDB, sunspot_solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sunspot, mongomapper, sunspot-rails

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application that uses MongoDB, and I have implemented basic Sunspot functionality. Here is some information about my environment

- Rails 3.2.11
- Mongo 2.4.3
- Sunspot 2.0.0
- gem mongo_mapper
- gem sunspot_rails
- gem sunspot_solr
- gem sunspot_mongo_mapper

I previously had everything working, but now I am having problems. I can successfully run

`bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`

<strike>but then when I try</strike>

`bundle exec rake db:seed`

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::InvalidRubyResponse - 200 OK
Error: <result status="1">java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XmlUpdateRequestHandler.doLegacyUpdate(XmlUpdateRequestHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrUpdateServlet.doPost(SolrUpdateServlet.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:297)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">Event 5197f9061d41c853110005a1</field><field name=\"type\">Event</field><field name=\"class_name\">Event</field><field name=\"name_text\">TEST Event Name</field><field name=\"description_text\">TEST Event Description</field></doc></add>"

Backtrace: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:297:in `rescue in evaluate_ruby_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:294:in `evaluate_ruby_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:269:in `adapt_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
(eval):2:in `post'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:87:in `add'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:106:in `add_documents'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:30:in `add'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:297:in `rescue in     evaluate_ruby_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:294:in `evaluate_ruby_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:269:in `adapt_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
(eval):2:in `post'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:87:in `add'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:106:in `add_documents'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:30:in `add'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-        2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot.rb:184:in `index'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:392:in `solr_index'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:492:in `perform_index_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:431:in `_run__816338171__save__410491902__callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/embedded_callbacks.rb:28:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/callbacks.rb:17:in `create_or_update'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:129:in `save'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:19:in `block in save'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:37:in `clear_changes'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:19:in `save'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/validations.rb:22:in `save'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/identity_map.rb:113:in `save'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:134:in `save!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:31:in `block in create!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:100:in `block in initialize_each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:98:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:98:in `initialize_each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:31:in `create!'
/my_home_dir/my_rails_app/db/seed_events.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/my_home_dir/my_rails_app/db/seeds.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/my_home_dir/my_rails_app/db/seeds.rb:16:in `each'
/my_home_dir/my_rails_app/db/seeds.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie/database.rake:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I *also* get a similar error if I attempt `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex` which has the same java.lang.NullPointerException stacktrace but a slightly different Ruby stacktrace.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry that I haven't gotten around to this in so long. I finally tried deleting my `solr/` directory and then restarting. I am now able to run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` and then `bundle exec rake db:seed` without any problems, but I still have an error when I try:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

I see the following stacktrace

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake aborted!
undefined method `includes' for Event:Class
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:39:in `method_missing'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:254:in `solr_index'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:203:in `solr_reindex'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:20:in `each'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/my_username.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So does anyone know what this problem is?

Any insight into this issue would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error only it was triggered with `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`, what helped was force quitting all java processes I could find. After I restarted SOLR with

`bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`

I could then reindex without any errors.

Comment: How do you identify which processes are using java?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17665820/227403

The solution was that my solr directory came over in a SVN deploy. I deleted the directory and restarted it.

Comment: I tried that, and I still get an error when I try to reindex. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

what's your solr/  directory structure, it should looks like:

```
sole/
  conf/
  data/
  pids/
```

My local machine has this 3 folders, it works. But both of my 2 server have no conf/. one works, the other does not works.

Beginning I try to delete whole solr/ folder, and restart solr, the problem still exist, then I reinstall java, reinstall gems, the problem still exist.

At last I add conf/ with some configure files that automatic created by solr at my local machine, I push them to sever, solve the problem.

It cost my whole day, hope this answer helpful.

Comment: the contents of my solr directory are:

      `conf/`,
      `data/`,
      `default/`,
      `development/`,
      `pids/`,
      `test/`, and
      `solr.xml`.

What are the configure files that are automatically created by solr on your machine? I am still getting an error when I try `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Pry & prey-debbugger to step in the last file and see what's going on.

/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:39:in `method_missing'

It's looking for something that no longer exists. Perhaps you've defined a field in Searchable that has been removed or changed?